# why my random chi square random sample shows error?

Tags: r

I want to generate a random sample of `chi square`. It generate pdf and quantile properly. but shows some problem in random sample. i think my main problem is in

```
u <- runif(n)
ans <- qchi(y=u, df=df)
```

This is my code:

```
pchi <- function(x,df)
{

integrand<-function(x){(1/(2^(df/2)*(gamma(df/2))))*((x^((df/2)-1))*exp(-1*(x/2)))}
ans <- integrate(integrand,lower=0,upper=x)
return(ans$value)
}

 ###quantile function of chi square 
qchi = function (y, df) {
uniroot(function (x) pchi(x, df) - y, lower = 0, upper = 10)$root
}

 ##random sample of chisquare

rchi <- function(n, df)
{
if(as.integer(n)!=n ||n<=0)
{
 stop("ERROR: n must be a positive integer value")
 }
 u <- runif(n)
ans <- qchi(y=u, df=df)
return(ans)
}
```

`pchi` and `qchi` runs properly. my problem is in `rchi`. when generate `rchi` it shows error:

> Error in uniroot(function(x) pchi(x, df) - y, lower = 0, upper = 10) : f() values at end points not of opposite sign In addition: Warning messages: 1: In if (is.na(f.lower)) stop("f.lower = f(lower) is NA") : the condition has length 1 and only the first element will be used 2: In if (is.na(f.upper)) stop("f.upper = f(upper) is NA") : the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

can any one help me?

Comment: Is there a good reason you're writing your own functions rather than using the chi square functions provided in the stats package included by default in R? Namely pchisq, qchisq, and rchisq?

Comment: Are you aware of the available functions listed at `?Chisquare`

Comment: yes. you are right. I have to this for my own. because i am learning r programming. yes i am aware of pchisq, qchisq, and rchisq. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rchi` works for n=1. However when n>1, because both `integrate` and `uniroot` only assumes scalar variable, rchi gives you error. You can sequentially assign values to `rchi`, as

```
rchi <- function(n, df)
{
    if(as.integer(n)!=n ||n<=0)
    {
        stop("ERROR: n must be a positive integer value")
    }
    u <- runif(n)
    ans <- numeric(n)
    for (i in 1:n) ans[i] <- qchi(y=u[i], df=df)
    return(ans)
}
```